# java ResultSet and statement issue

Tags: java, mysql

i don't understand why my variable **state** cannot be resolved.

i'm in a java Mysql project.

Here is the Commands class code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class Commands {

    public Commands() throws SQLException{
        Connection conn = DbConn.getInstance();
        Statement state = conn.createStatement();
    }

    public String getList(){
        System.out.println("Here is a List of our Products:");
        // Get list from db
        ResultSet result = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM products");
        ResultSetMetaData resultMeta = result.getMetaData();
        // Display the List

        System.out.println("List displayed");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the DbConn class code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class DbConn {
      private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB";
      private static String user = "root";
      private static String passwd = "";
      private static Connection connect;

      // create new instance if not exists
       public static Connection getInstance(){
           if(connect == null){
                try {
                    connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
           }      
           return connect;  
      }   
}
```

My code is not finished yet, but the message come on this line:

```
ResultSet result = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM products");
```

My Eclipse editor says this message **state cannot be resolved**

Any idea?

Comment: `state` is a local variable in constructor `commands` and cannot be accessed in the method `getList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a matter of scope. You define the variable here

```
public Commands() throws SQLException{
    Connection conn = DbConn.getInstance();
    Statement state = conn.createStatement();
}
```

And that is the only place the variable is visible - in the constructor. Define it in the class and initialize it in the constructor:

```
private Connection conn = null;
private Statement state = null;

public Commands() throws SQLException{
    conn = DbConn.getInstance();
    state = conn.createStatement();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare "State" outside of that constructor.

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement state = null;

public Commands() throws SQLException{
    conn = DbConn.getInstance();
    state = conn.createStatement();
}
```